# Import issue with SQL Server 2014 SSIS - ORDINAL POSITION is invalid

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ordinal

When importing from a CacheODBC DB I get the same error for a column attribute:

> Cannot load the column attributes from the schema using the current provider descriptor:
>
> The column attribute "ORDINAL_POSITION" is not valid.
>   The column attribute "COLUMN_SIZE" is not valid.
>   The column attribute "DECIMAL_DIGITS" is not valid.
>   The column attribute "COLUMN_SIZE" is not valid.
>
> Please verify the ProviderDescriptors.xml file contains the data provider descriptor that matches the schema of the used data provider.

I had some advice ref the "ProvidorDescriptors" file - where I had to edit some fields - this worked with exception to the ORDINAL_POSITION which is now the only failure

Can anyone point me to how this is fixed ...

Thanks

Comment: What value are you using for the Ordinal Position?

Comment: Tab - to be honest I am unsure, all looks good if I view the file and being new to integration I don't know where I should look for its original value ...thanks for replying so quick